# Automate process to send email attachment to remote server

Tags: linux, vba, powershell, outlook, email-attachments

At our company we're receiving excel files as attachments per mail (Outlook). These excel tables have to be copied manually to a remote server (linux) in order to be processed. I'd like to fully automate this process (without any manual step) but it doesn't seem easy because it has to be done without any third party tool.

My ideas sofar:

1. Creating a VBA script that saves the excel into a folder, then a powershell script transfers it to the remote server. The problem is with that solution that the Outlook has to be opened for that. Its not so practical because of the client side components. It must be working without starting any clients computer.
2. Using Power Automate to create a flow that copies the attachments into the Onedrive, then somehow copy the files to the Linux server with a bash script. But it seems also a bit trickier than I thought because it's not so easy to download a file from a corporate Onedrive to a Linux machine.

Is there anyone who has already done something similar or has a better idea?

Any help/idea would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd use the Microsoft Graph API to download the file, and then the Posh-SSH PowerShell module to push the file over to the Linux machine.

Comment: Never used it before. I'll check it.

Comment: What account do you have configured in Outlook? Is it Exchange? Office 365 (i.e. Exchange online)? IMAP? Any SMTP account?

Comment: We have Office 365

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA in Outlook to pull all attached files from selected folder. Here's an example of VBA code;

```
Sub PullAttachments()
    Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outNames As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim outFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim outAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    
    ' The path where you want to save attached files <<<<<<
    strPath = "C:\Your\path\" 
    
    Set outApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set outNames = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' Select the Outlook folder to pull attached files
    Set outFolder = outNames.PickFolder
    
    ' Check if a folder is selected
    If Not outFolder Is Nothing Then

        For Each outMail In outFolder.Items
            ' Check if the email has attachments
            If outMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                ' Loop through the attachments
                For Each outAttachment In outMail.Attachments
                    ' Check the attachment file type <<<<<<<<<
                    If Right(outAttachment.FileName, 4) = "xlsx" Then
                        ' Build the full file path
                        strFile = strPath & outAttachment.FileName
                        ' Save the attachment to the specified folder
                        outAttachment.SaveAsFile strFile
                    End If
                Next outAttachment
            End If
        Next outMail
    End If
    
    Set outAttachment = Nothing
    Set outMail = Nothing
    Set outFolder = Nothing
    Set outNames = Nothing
    Set outApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is with VBA that I have to open Outlook for that (client side). I'm thinking about a solution that is working without my PC (server side).

Answer (score 0):

Any client-side solutions requires client applications running on the system to get the code running. If you deal with Office 365 you may consider creating a service from which you could the [MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) where you could retrieve the attached files and upload them to your server. Of course, if you deal with Exchange Online.

In case of Exchange on-premise you may consider using EWS, see [EWS applications and the Exchange architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/ews-applications-and-the-exchange-architecture) for more information.

Comment: So theoretically it could work. But what about Power Automate? Isn't it easier than creating a service in MS Graph?

Comment: Okay. I've found some infos about that. Maybe it would be nicer if I would call this API directly from Linux with a curl command (download the file).  Is there any way to do that?